# Webpack won't compile js files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

After running `webpack --watch` on cli, all the files compile and all is good! But after updating webpack, it doesn't trigger watch when js files are changed and only does and exports for css.

My webpack config:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
    path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
      './client.js',
      './client/styles/main.scss'
    ],
    output: {
        path: './build',
        publicPath: '/public/js/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js'],
      alias: {
        'styles': __dirname + '/client/styles',
        'components': __dirname + '/client/scripts/components',
        'actions': __dirname + '/client/scripts/actions',
        'stores': __dirname + '/client/scripts/stores',
        'constants': __dirname + '/client/scripts/constants',
        'mixins': __dirname + '/client/scripts/mixins',
        'configs': __dirname + '/client/scripts/configs',
        'icon': 'react-fa'
      }
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
        { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: require.resolve('babel-loader') },
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},
        { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' },
        { test: /\.scss$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader',
            'css!sass?outputStyle=expanded&' +
              "includePaths[]=" +
                (path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules"))
          )
        },
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery",
          "windows.jQuery": "jquery"
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css", {allChunks: true}),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin()
    ],
    stats: {
      colors: true,
      reasons: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    watch: true,
    keepalive: true,
    debug: true,
    cache: true,
};
```

My output:

```
Version: webpack 1.9.6
Time: 4153ms
                                 Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot   20.1 kB          [emitted]
  89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg    109 kB          [emitted]
  e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf   45.4 kB          [emitted]
 fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff   23.4 kB          [emitted]
448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2     18 kB          [emitted]
                               main.js   1.11 MB       0  [emitted]  main
                              main.css    164 kB       0  [emitted]  main
                           main.js.map   1.31 MB       0  [emitted]  main
                          main.css.map  85 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 40 bytes {0} [built]
    + 249 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
                                     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
      f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot  20.1 kB          [emitted]
      89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg   109 kB          [emitted]
      e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf  45.4 kB          [emitted]
     fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff  23.4 kB          [emitted]
    448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2    18 kB          [emitted]
        + 7 hidden modules
```

No other output is created when JS changes.
     .....

```
 file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_vendor-prefixes.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_alerts.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_buttons.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_panels.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_pagination.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_list-group.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_nav-divider.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_forms.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_progress-bar.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_table-row.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_background-variant.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_border-radius.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_gradients.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_clearfix.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_center-block.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_nav-vertical-align.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_grid-framework.scss' }
{ file: '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/frontend/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_grid.scss' }
```

After CSS change.

Answer (score 0):

The config for your JS loader is different from the others; does it work if you change

```
{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: require.resolve('babel-loader') }
```

to

```
{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
```